# Acceder a tablas con Entity Framework en C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

Acabo de empezar con C# y Entity Framework en Visual Studio 2019 y Core 3

Después de crear el modelo de datos con scaffold, cuando intento hacer una simple prueba de acceso a los datos, no tengo nada claro qué necesito usar en el using u otro método.

Este sería el aspecto de la solución:

[image: Solución C#]

Este sería parte del aspecto del modelo de datos XMLTables.cs:

[image: Modelo de datos]

No acabo de entender qué necesita el using para acceder a la BBDD.

Si en el scaffold, para crear el modelo de datos se ha indicado un nombre:

-Context XMLTables

, entiendo que este debería ser el necesario:

[image: Using XMLTables]

He probado sin éxito con otros nombres tipo:

using (NovesInterfases db = new NovesInterfases())
...

Gracias

Comment: Si recien empezaste con EF, entonces lo mejor que podes hacer es leer mil tutoriales de EF.. no necesitas un using, estas usando EF.. tus entidades se conectan solas a la DB a traves del dbcontext...  o sea.. que haciendo XMLTables ya tenes tu conexion a la base de datos, y solo tenes que usar los set que contiene.. particularmente, por lo que decis, estas esperando algo menos "magico"... tal vez te sirva otro ORM?

Comment: Estoy usando el using por verlo en un tutorial de C# y Entity Framework, toda la documentación encontrada se basa en lo mismo. Si hay otra manera más fácil o adecuada, pues perfecto, mucho mejor. ¿Qué otra fórmula existe, es decir, como se declararía un acceso a través del dbcontext que ya tengo?. Gracias

Comment: Espera... mea culpa, me maree... pone el codigo como texto, siempre... cual es el error que te marca? te esta faltando un using??? el using es correcto...

Comment: El `using (XMLTables db = new XMLTables())`, genera el error: "El nombre del tipo o del espacio de nombres 'XMLTables' no se encontró".

De todas maneras, la otra manera que conozco de acceder a los datos sería algo como: `var pedidos = _context.Ipcabpe.ToList();`, pero _context o dbcontext por ejemplo tampoco le gustan. Gracias

Comment: A pesar de que todos los archivos están bajo la misma solución, ¿quizás para acceder al modelo de datos desde ConnectBBDD.cs, aquí debería hacerse algún using en la cabecera que permita reconocer los objetos de datos tipo `using NovesInterfases.Models;`?. Gracias

Comment: Te falta un `using NovesInterfases.Models` al comienzo del archivo

Comment: Perfecto, ya funciona añadiendo en la cabecera el using al modelo de datos. Si quisiera usar la otra fórmula `var pedidos = _context.Ipcabpe.ToList();` de acceso, ¿Qué prefijo necesito visto que _context, dbcontext o XMLTables no van?. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

La inexperiencia, daba por seguro que al formar parte de la misma solución no era necesario un using en la cabecera y si, ahora ya funciona:

```
using NovesInterfases.Models;
```

Gracias